# Getting checkbox values in HTML to a temporary variable Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of checkboxes, with the same id="cbna", but when i submit the form , the javascript code should check If atleat one checkbox is checked, if not an alert should pop up. if it is checked the the value stored in site the checkbox should execute along with the details of a text area. I have tried to do the same but in vain.

```
    <script>

 function checkCheckBoxes(form1) 
     {
    if (document.form1.checked==true)
              {
        function OpenWindow(info)
               {
                   window.open(info);
               }
              }
else
    {
 alert ('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!');
 return false;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" >
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked)OpenWindow(this.value)}" value="www.something.com 1" />
  google<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked){OpenWindow(this.value)}" value="www.something.com 2" />
  apple<br />

 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked){OpenWindow(this.value)}" value="www.something.com 3" />
  ibm<br />

 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked){OpenWindow(this.value)}" value="www.something.com 4" />
  nageo<br />

 <textarea cols="100" rows="22" id="descp" >
 hello wats up!
</textarea>
 <input onclick="checkCheckBoxes(form1)" value="create forms" type="button">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey @Hatake use below code..

Answer (score 0):

hey @HatakeKakashi use below code for your problem

page1.html code

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>page1</title>
            </head>
             <script>
                     function checkCheckBoxes() 
                    {
                    var flag=false;
                       var elLength = document.form1.elements.length;

                        for (i=0; i<elLength; i++)
                        {
                            var type = form1.elements[i].type;
                            if (type=="checkbox" && form1.elements[i].checked){

                                flag =true;
                            }
                            else if (type=="checkbox") {
                               // alert("not checked");
                            }
                        }

                        if(flag)
                        {
                         window.open("page2.html?textVal="+document.form1.descp.value,'mywindow','width=400,height=200')
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert ("You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes!");
                            return false;
                        }
                   }
        </script>
            <body>
                           <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" >
                      <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="" value="www.something.com 1" />
                      google<br />
                     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="" value="www.something.com 2" />
                      apple<br />

                     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="" value="www.something.com 3" />
                      ibm<br />

                     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onclick="" value="www.something.com 4" />
                      nageo<br />

                     <textarea cols="100" rows="22" id="descp" >hello wats up!</textarea>
                     <input onclick="checkCheckBoxes(form1)" value="create forms" type="button">
                    </form>
            </body>
        </html>
```

page2.html code

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Page2</title>
          <script>
          function getURLParameters(paramName) 
                {
                        var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();  
                    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
                    {
                       var arrParams = sURL.split("?");         
                       var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");      
                       var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
                       var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);     
                       var i = 0;
                       for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
                       {
                        var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
                        arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
                        if (sParam[1] != "")
                            arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
                        else
                            arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
                       }

                       for (i=0;i<arrURLParams.length;i++)
                       {
                                if(arrParamNames[i] == paramName){
                            //alert("Param:"+arrParamValues[i]);
                                return arrParamValues[i];
                             }
                       }
                       return "No Parameters Found";
                    }

                }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
           <script>
                    document.write(getURLParameters("textVal"))
           </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, one more issue, currently, when i check a check box, the link that is bound to the check box opens in a new tab. But is it possible to check all the required boxes and only when i click the submit button all the tabs should open.and all the contents of the text area should come to the new form.

Comment: @HatakeKakashi can you tell me you are using jsp file or html file

Comment: Im using only html and javascript

Comment: My apologies for asking, but what is the page2.html used for, I mean its purpose

Comment: i used page2.html for display your text in new open window

Comment: and you can do this things as a pop up window also